# Add a second texture to Sascha Willems' glftLoading app

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am working with Sascha Willems' Vulkan code:

https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/master/examples/gltfloading

https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/data/shaders/glsl/gltfloading/mesh.vert

https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/data/shaders/glsl/gltfloading/mesh.frag

I cannot figure out how to pass multiple textures into the fragment shader using C++. I know what to do in the GLSL code, because it's the same as in OpenGL 4.

Has anyone had any luck adding a second texture into this example code?

The glTF mesh that I am working with is at https://github.com/sjhalayka/pedestal_textures/raw/main/ped_tex.zip

Sorry for such a n00b question, but I'm totally stuck. Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Most of us aren't familiar with the example/tutorial you reference, so to help you, we'd need to go learn it, then guess how you're trying to reimplement it. You'll get a far better response if you include the relevant snippets in the question, including your own attempt(s).